# Evaluating derivative of $\int^{3x}_{2x} \sin(t^3 + 1) \,\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Maybe I'm not very good at my trig rules but I'm having a tough time finding derivative of

$$\int^{3x}_{2x} \sin(t^3 + 1) \,\mathrm dt$$

I believe that $u = t^3 + 1$ and $du = 3t^2$, but I'm not sure how to get that to fit back into the integral? I can't just do $-\cos(3t^2)$ can I?

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Don't evaluate the integral

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int^{3x}_{2x} \sin(t^3 + 1) \,\mathrm  dt=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{3x} \sin(t^3 + 1) \,\mathrm  dt-\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{2x} \sin(t^3 + 1) \,\mathrm dt$$

Now use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

For example for first  we get

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{3x} \sin(t^3 + 1) \,\mathrm  dt=\sin((3x)^3 + 1)\cdot3=3\sin(27x^3 + 1)$$

Can you do the rest and put results together?

Comment: is the answer then $3sin(27x^3 +1) - 2sin(8x^3+1)$

Comment: @KillerSmalls Exactly! Good job!